# cannot connect to android node

Tags: ros-indigo, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I am trying to run ros on an Android device using rosjava.
I have first tried downloading the android_sensors_driver app from the Market and everything works fine: I can start a roscore on my laptop and connect to it from the app and I can log all imu/gps data.

However if I try the same with the latest version of the app from the git repo https://github.com/ros-android/android_sensors_driver it does not work.

I had no problems compiling. When I run the app, I set the master uri with the ip of my laptop and the app says it successfully connected to the master. However when I run rosnode list, I cannot see the app and neither I can see the topics it publishes.

I also tried with the other tutorial apps in https://github.com/rosjava/android_core but they all do the same: they seem to connect to the master, but no node/topic shows up.

I found other people having similar issues and I did these checks/tests:

- both the smartphone and the laptop are connected to the same wifi network
- both can ping each other
- there should be no special firewall in the router and I also tried connecting both devices to a third android device working as a hot spot
- I tried different phones

I am using ros indigo and Android kitkat.

Thank you very much for any help.
Cheers.

Riccardo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203522/cannot-connect-to-android-node/) by [rick187](https://answers.ros.org/users/4440/rick187/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2015-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might have run into this [bug](https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/issues/231) which has been fixed in Feb. Does your code utilise this bugfix?

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2015-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0